# How to display icon in column header with w2ui grid

Tags: jquery, w2ui

When I click the icon using fa-plus-square-o and fa-minus-square-o of awe icon, I execute the method of showColumn (), hideColumn () of w2ui grid, I wanted to show accordion.

It was realized with the following code.
When the refresh of grid was done, the state of the icon returned to the initial state, which was very difficult.

How do you do the easiest way to display icons in the grid column headers, handle click events and redraw them?

The version of w2ui at the time of development is 1.4.3, but it is OK with version 1.5.

```
    columns: [{
        field: 'col02',
        caption: ''
            +'<div>'
            +' <div>'
            +'  <i class="fa fa-lg text-danger fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
            +' </div>'
            +' <div>'
            +  '<span class="vertical">vert title</span>'
            +' </div>'
            +'</div>',
        size: '70px',
//      sortable: true,  <- By the way, sorting did not work when picking up a click event
        attr: 'align=right',
        resizable : true,
        render: function(record, index, col_index) {
            return (record.col02 == 0 ? '-' : record.col02.toFixed(2));
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I don't completely understand your question, but it seems there's a missing ``"`` in this line: ``'  <i class="fa fa-lg text-danger fa-plus-square-o aria-hidden="true"></i>'`` - maybe that's the reason why your icon does not show?

Comment: sorry. it's typo.What I would like to ask you is how to easily accomplish this same thing.